# Apache Spark MLlib : OLS regression in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have been looking at the documentation of Apache Spark MLlib, and can't seem to find Linear Regression that uses Ordinary Least Squares (OLS).
I only see examples of the numerical based algorithm for Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) method of doing Linear Regression. I need the closed form OLS Linear Regression method, not SGD.

I am surprised how hard it is to try to find OLS regression in this, when OLS regression is one of the first most basic of Linear Regression methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to find because Spark doesn't provide an implementation. The rationale is pretty simple. If you have data which requires Spark then the cost of computing an analytical solution will be prohibitive.

If you really need this then [`RowMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix) provides `tallSkinnyQR`. It should give you something to work with although it is rather unlikely to be useful in practice.

Comment: OK, thanks. I got a sense that they did not include it. I did not know the rational behind this. I am trying to mimic another software and it uses OLS regression. When I tried to use SGD in regression it gives different results either slightly close or off. SO I was hoping that in Apache Spark they implemented OLS.

Comment: I looked at Apache Commons Math, but it seems their documentation is outdated with their current release. Its really hard to try to figure out. SO I was wondering if hence anyone knows of another java project that has OLS implemented.

Comment: Weka? http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/LinearRegression.html

Comment: Hi zero323, I see you made reference to these :RowMatrix provides tallSkinnyQR. When I looked at this, it seems that these are Matrix based operations/methods that one can use to implement OLS regression. But I can't commit to going thru trying to learn and implement it myself. I would have done it already if I was really wanting to implement this on my own. BUT I like the fact you referred me to this, I was not aware they have all these nice Matrix methods in the docs.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for the weka reference. I almost forgot about weka. I looked at your link, but can't seem to find where it says it uses OLS under the hood. So I don't know what it is using under the hood.

Comment: Hi, I did a quick search and found this about weka linear regression: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?139519-Linear-regression-with-weka%28used-method-for-estimate-linear-coefficients%29

Comment: It seems to use Gradient Descent as well.

Comment: I think I am wrong, I read it too quickly, my own link. It seems to have both implemented. SO thanks so much zero323!!! You have directed me to find that which I need. Thanks again!!

Comment: what a rollercoaster